# Pairwise correlations in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

I have a dataframe as following,

```
print(df)
    SAS_a1  SAS2_a1 SAS3_a1 FDF_b1  FDF2_b1
0   0.673114    0.745755    0.989468    0.498920    0.837440
1   0.811218    0.392196    0.505301    0.615603    0.946847
2   0.252856    0.709125    0.321580    0.826123    0.224813
3   0.566833    0.738661    0.626808    0.815460    0.003738
4   0.102995    0.171741    0.246565    0.784519    0.980965
```

I aiming to pairwise correlation using `pearsonr` and but I wanted the pairwise correlation between columns ending with a1 versus b1. The final result should look like,

```
                     PCC   p-value
SAS_a1__FDF_b1 -0.293373  0.631895
SAS_a1__FDF2_b1 -0.947724  0.014235
SAS2_a1__FDF_b1 0.771389  0.126618
SAS2_a1__FDF2_b1 e  0.132380  0.831942
SAS3_a1__FDF_b1  0.422249  0.478808
SAS3_a1__FDF2_b1  0.346411  0.567923
```

Any suggestions would be great ..!!!
Here is what I tried,

```
columns = df.columns.tolist()
for col_a, col_b in itertools.combinations(columns, 2):
    correlations[col_a + '__' + col_b] = pearsonr(df.loc[:, col_a], df.loc[:, col_b])
results = DataFrame.from_dict(correlations, orient='index')
results.columns = ['PCC', 'p-value']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if its the most elegant solution but you can use list comprehension to create a list containing the relevant columns:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
result = pd.DataFrame()
for a1 in [column for column in df.columns if 'a1' in column]:
  for b1 in [column for column in df.columns if 'b1' in column]:
    result = result.append(
               pd.Series(
                 pearsonr(df[a1],df[b1]),
                 index=['PCC', 'p-value'],
                 name=a1 + '__' +b1
               ))
```

PS: It would be great if you would include your imports in your next question. (So that people answering don't have to google it)

Comment: Thanks but the results dataframe is empty

Comment: Strange, it works for me. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: '0.18.1' is the version I ma using

Comment: Ok, i have 0.20.3, possibly thats the root of error. Are you able to upgrade? Otherwise you probably need to change the way the result df is build in the loop.

Comment: Yes, But I have boot versions, I tried on the 0.20.3, it now works fine.Thanks for the solution !!!

Comment: Sorry, there an issue when the dimension changes, for example, I tried on another data frame and it throws this error message.  ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (82,2) (82,)

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more the shape of your dataframe and which line causes the error?

Comment: The dataframe is of (82, 1032) shape and the last line result = result.append(
               pd.Series(
                 pearsonr(df[a1],df[b1]),
                 index=['PCC', 'p-value'],
                 name=a1 + '__' +b1
               ) throws out error

Comment: Can you try it with this [code](https://gist.github.com/P-Tillmann/d952a928c51cdf3167e87eeeec55709c) and see where the error is thrown? Do you have duplicated column names by any chance?

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (82,2) (82,) 
Yes I see a duplicated colmumn name but the values are different, in that case is there a solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161472/discussion-between-user1017373-and-p-tillmann).